# Как пофиксить зависание инсталлятора в ubuntu?

Tags: linux-mint, apt-get

Добрый день, пытался инсталлировать в linux mint - sendmail, инсталляция как-то затормозилась на одном месте и теперь похоже блокируется установка другого по. пытался поставить себе icedtea - вывелось сообщение 
"dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem" и после запуска этой команды все вновь зависло на инсталляции sendmail[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорей всего он не завис, а ждёт пока генератор случайных чисел накопит энтропию для генерации ключей. Подвигай мышкой, пожмакай клавиши, поднеси урановый пруток к своему счётчику гейгера и это всё скоро закончится...

Comment: Это не убунту, а минт.

Comment: Кстати, вообще-то генерация ключа реально может брать источником случайных чисел всякие движения мыши и нажатия кнопок, хотя странно, если она об этом не предупреждает.